# SQL injection for the following regular expression

Tags: sql, sql-injection

I am looking for backdoors in various softwares and wondering if the following code is vulnerable to a sql injection.

There's an email field with the following validation expression. (ASPX/CS)

```
ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*">
```

Is it possible to exploit the above to drop a table for example or do anything malicious using a SQL injection?

Thanks
Regards

EDIT 1: People have asked me how this was implemented —

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(snpConnectionString);
SqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
conn.Open();
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TABLE_ VALUES ('" + TextBoxFN.Text + "','" + TextBoxLN.Text + "','" + sb1.ToString() + "','" + TextBoxEA.Text + "','" + sb.ToString() + "',0,'" + DateTime.Now + "')";
try{
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
}
catch
{
    Response.Redirect("Error.aspx", true);
}
```

TextBoxEA.text corresponds to the email address.

Comment: Well, that depends a lot on how the field is used later on.

Comment: Give an example of valid input to help understand the RegEx?

Comment: I've updated the main post with the usage.

Comment: Don't try to validate the input.  Use parametrized queries.  Then you don't have to ask this question.

Comment: I have NOT written this code. I am looking for backdoors and a SQL injection seems to be a possibility. Henceforth — the question: Is there a possibility of a SQL injection in this code?

Comment: This does come across as you trying to get the SO community to do your work for you. Just saying.

Comment: When you say SQL, do you mean Microsoft Sql Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expression validation is great for the UI or business layer to check user input to prevent errors.

It is less great for preventing SQL injection.

If the code does not use parameterized queries, it is vulnerable either now, or later after someone makes a minor error updating the regular expression to conform to a new business requirement.

Answer (score 1):

It is best to use parameterized queries like Eric stated, but looking at the regex only the following characters are valid

```
A-Za-z0-9_-+.'
```

Without a space I don't think they could inject SQL, but if it was me I'd still make sure to use parameterized queries to be safe.